# "Firebase deploy" works even after "firebase logout"

Tags: firebase

I logged out of my firebase account from local machine CLI using `firebase logout`.
Then I try to deploy using `firebase deploy` and it still works.
I want to revoke access so that I should get authorization error.
Tried restarting terminal.

Comment: Just a guess, do you also have the google cloud cli installed? Possible you need to logout of both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to [Link](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions) to revoke firebase access for your account.
Then you wont be able to deploy and would need to re-authenticate